# How can I apply a lightbox (prettyphoto) to all images in the content div?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, lightbox

I have a lightbox script installed and now I want to apply the script on every image within the content div. How can I achieve this?

My current JS code:

```
       <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
  $(document).ready(function(){
   $("a[rel^='prettyPhoto']").prettyPhoto();
  });
 </script>
```

The css/div I want it applied to:

```
div.post img {
```

I somehow can't get this to work, and my jQuery skills are non existent :)

Thanks in advance for any help :)

Comment: Maybe `$("div.post img a[rel='prettyPhoto']").prettyPhoto();`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently, you're finding all `<a>` tags with `rel='prettyPhoto'` and using the prettyPhoto() plugin on them.

You can apply the same methodology to your `div.post img {`selector, by doing something like:

```
$("div.post img").prettyPhoto();
```

All I did was **change the JQuery selector to match the div css identifier you provided**. So, prettyPhoto() will be applied to all elements in "div.post img".

Comment: Hi guys, I think I see where the problem lies, and why your suggestions are not working.. the image is linked to the full version so the div selector should be different.. I should open the linked full size image when clicked on the resized image in the content div!

$("a[rel^='prettyPhoto']").prettyPhoto();

Should be something like:

$("a[divl^='div.post img a']").prettyPhoto();

I think? thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2):

Uhh, maybe

```
$('div.post img').prettyPhoto();
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer.. I tried that but I does not seem to work.. I'm using WordPress btw and prettyphoto works fine the "normal" way.

Comment: Well what do you mean when you say that it "does not seem to work"?  What happens? Are there errors in your Firebug console?  Does anything happen at all?

Comment: Hi guys, I think I see where the problem lies, and why your suggestions are not working.. the image is linked to the full version so the div selector should be different.. I should open the linked full size image when clicked on the resized image in the content div!

$("a[rel^='prettyPhoto']").prettyPhoto();

Should be something like:

$("a[divl^='div.post img a']").prettyPhoto();

I think? thanks for the help!

Comment: at Maxim: yes I mean WordPress but the selfhosted version of it :)

Comment: You selector syntax sure does look strange to me.  What is that supposed to mean?  Stuff in square brackets is supposed to refer to element attribute values.